# SQLSERVER FOR XML PATH - treat attributes name as variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
SELECT field1 as "@q1_12"
FROM table1
FOR XML PATH ('qt'),TYPE
```

I need to shape the result of this query in xml, but the field's alias "@q1_12" should change according to different and complicated conditions.

So, is it possible to put the name of this attribute in a variable and use it in the query (like a sort of dynamic sql)
Is there some trick or workaround?

```
SELECT field1 as @attributename  <-- this is a variable
FROM table1
FOR XML PATH ('qt'),TYPE
```

i know that, here the character '@' makes confusion, it has different meaning of treated either as variable or as literal(in this example it will be used by "XML FOR" command to put the field’s value into an attribute instead of an element)

Moreover this query is used as subquery, so using CASE/IF is very difficult, any ideas?

Comment: Could you use something that won't occur in the data as the attribute name and then replace that string with the one you want?

Comment: Easiest way is probably to just do a textual replacement; neither SQL nor XML like dynamic result sets, and if this is part of a bigger query you can't use an FLWOR queries to solve it either. That is, `SELECT CONVERT(XML, REPLACE((SELECT field1 AS [@_DynamicAttribute_] ... FOR XML PATH ('qt')), '_DynamicAttribute_', @attributename))`. We're charitably assuming `_DynamicAttribute_` won't occur in the source. Depending on your actual query, splicing this in as a subquery might take some doing, but it is at least nominally possible (you can embed typed XML in other XML).

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows clearly, that you know about dynamic SQL and your got some hints about `REPLACE()` to solve this on string level.

### suggestion 1

But there might be an approach, especially if the possible names are all known and the list is not to big:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('Row 1'),('Row 2');
```

--As you know, it is **impossible** to use a variable column alias...
--You can use a dynamic statement, but this involves some major draw-backs... (no ad-hoc, difficult to proceed with the output...)

--But you might try this
--To simulate your *complex conditions* I just check for one single value (but you'll get the ghist):

```
DECLARE @SomeCondition INT=2;

SELECT CASE WHEN @SomeCondition=1 THEN SomeValue END AS [@q1_01]
      ,CASE WHEN @SomeCondition=2 THEN SomeValue END AS [@q1_02]
      ,CASE WHEN @SomeCondition=3 THEN SomeValue END AS [@q1_03]
      --add all possible attribute names here...
FROM @mockupTable t
FOR XML PATH('qt'),TYPE;
```

The magic behind: If not specified explicitly (Read about `ELEMENTS XSINIL`) the XML created with `FOR XML PATH()` will omit NULL values.
You can state all possible column names and all of them will be omitted, if the condition is not reached.

### suggestion 2

this is the opposite approach:

```
DECLARE @KeepThis VARCHAR(100)='q1_02';
SELECT
(
    SELECT SomeValue AS [@q1_01]
          ,SomeValue AS [@q1_02]
          ,SomeValue AS [@q1_03]
    FROM @mockupTable t
    FOR XML PATH('qt'),TYPE
).query('for $qt in /qt
         return
         <qt>
         { 
         for $a in $qt/@*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@KeepThis")]
         return $a
         }
         </qt>');
```

The XML will be created with all attributes *side-by-side*, while the XQuery will return just the one we want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is with dynamic SQL. You cannot use a variable to replace the value of a object, alias, etc. Therefore you will need to **safely** inject it into the statement:

```sql
DECLARE @attributename sysname = N'@q1_12';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT field1 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@attributename) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM table1' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FOR XML PATH ('qt'),TYPE;';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: The query returns the data as "XML type" as you can see `FOR XML PATH ('qt'),**TYPE**`, so the next question is: is it possible to use the result of `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL`  in a **subquery**?

Comment: @alex No. You'll need to use a `REPLACE` method for that, as @JeroenMostert suggests.